# delegate flickering loop

Tags: jquery, delegates, hover, infinite-loop, flicker

I have been using delegate to get the hover effect working on a nested div. But it seems to cause a flickering loop and I have no idea how to stop it.

The `.shadow` div is the height and width of it's parent div, `.box`.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="box">
          <div class="hover"><h2>Joe Bloggs</h2></div>
          <div class="cover"></div>
          <div class="shadow"></div>
          <img class="image" src="_assets/images/joebloggs.jpg" alt="" />
       </div>
    </div>

    $(".wrapper").delegate(".shadow", "mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
       if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
          $(this).parent().find('.cover').show();
          $(this).parent().find('.hover').show();
       } else {
          $(this).parent().find('.cover').hide();
          $(this).parent().find('.hover').hide();
       }
    });
```

Comment: When you show `cover` and `hover`, it becomes under the cursor, triggering the mouseout, hididng `cover` and `hover` causing the mouseover again in an endless loop. If you isntead used mouseenter/mouseleave and made `cover` and `hover` children of shadow, you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Kevin B Ah of course, how dumb of me! I feel so foolish now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kevin B Fixed due to your comment, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your events are being triggered in an infinite loop while hovering over the target element.

1. Mouse enters `.shadow`
2. `.cover` and `.hover` are displayed
3. Mouse leaves `.shadow` due to `.hover` being displayed
4. `.cover` and `.hover` are hidden
5. (GoTo 1. unless mouse is no longer over any of the three)

If you instead used mouseenter/mouseleave and made `cover` and `hover` children of `shadow`, you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recode to the new jQuery methods (.on / mouseenter, .delegate is now obselete) to see if this has the desired effect:

```
$(".wrapper").on("mouseenter", ".shadow", function(e) {
   $(this).parent().find('.cover').show();
   $(this).parent().find('.hover').show();
}).on("mouseleave", ".shadow", function(e) {
   $(this).parent().find('.cover').hide();
   $(this).parent().find('.hover').hide();
});
```